# Using JSLint in Notepad++

Tags: javascript, notepad++, jslint, lint

I have seen other text editors use extensions to allow syntax checkers such as [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com), is this possible with Notepad++?

Comment: This isn't an answer but this code: (function() { if(!JSLINT(WScript.StdIn.ReadAll(),{passfail:false})) { var e; for(var i in JSLINT.errors) { e=JSLINT.errors[i]; WScript.StdOut.WriteLine('Lint at line '+(e.line+1)+' character '+(e.character+1)+': '+e.reason); WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(' '+(e.evidence||'').replace(/^\s*(\S*(\s+\S+)*)\s*$/,"$1")); } WScript.Quit(1); } }()); Is giving me this on Notepad++ console: > Lint at line 79 character 8: Stopping,
> unable to continue. (39% scanned).
> C:\Program Files\JSLint\jslint.js(4637, 17)
> Microsoft JScript runtime error:
> 'line' is null or not an

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You may try JSLint Plugin for Notepad++:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/jslintnpp/

Comment: +1. You install this simply by downloading a DLL into the Notepad++ plugins directory. You immediately get JSLint, with a nice "options" dialog where you can customise the JSLint options, including changing the max number of errors that will be output. I really was up and running in less time than it took me just to **read** the [currently accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046810/using-jslint-in-notepad/1046826#1046826). Let alone actually making all those edits to JS, config and batch files that it describes.

Comment: This is far better written than my solution.

Comment: FWIW, you don't have to manually install it any more - you can just select it from the list of available plugins.  I love Notepad++'s plugin manager! see sshot @ http://i.imgur.com/Sap38.png

Comment: Unfortunately, the plugin seems to be broken with the latest version of both JSLint (gives "Unknown exception" error dialog) and JSHint (gives "Invalid JSLint Script!" error dialog). Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Too bad it's only for 32-bit NPP :(.

Answer (score 44):

I have managed to get two lint programs to run using the [notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/)'s [NppExec](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=189927&package_id=224034) Plugin.

The NppExec plugin is usually installed by default and can be found under plugins -> NppExec. (Using NppExec 0.3 RC1 and Notepad++ 5.1+).

### 1) JSLint

first download the [WSH version of jslint](http://www.jslint.com/wsh/index.html) from http://www.jslint.com.
Modify the last part of the file as follows:

```
(function() {
    if(!JSLINT(WScript.StdIn.ReadAll(),{passfail:false})) {
        var e;
        for(var i in JSLINT.errors) {
            e=JSLINT.errors[i];
            WScript.StdOut.WriteLine('Lint at line '+(e.line+1)+' character '+(e.character+1)+': '+e.reason);
            WScript.StdOut.WriteLine('    '+(e.evidence||'').replace(/^\s*(\S*(\s+\S+)*)\s*$/,"$1"));
        }
        WScript.Quit(1);
    }
}());
```

[(Pre-modified version here)](http://lynet.ca/~alumb/jslint/jslint.js)
This causes JSLint to output all of the errors, not just the first one.

Next, Notepad++'s NppExec doesn't allow the use of StdIn so I wrote a [batch file](http://lynet.ca/~alumb/jslint/jslint.bat) to actually execute the command.
This also allowed me to add a config file that is inserted before all javascript files. The options can be seen [here](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#options).
The batch file looks like this:

```
@copy /b "C:\Program Files\jslint\conf.txt"+%1 "C:\Program Files\jslint\lastoutput.txt" > temp.txt
@cscript /Nologo "C:\Program Files\jslint\jslint.js" < "C:\Program Files\jslint\lastoutput.txt"
```

You may need to modify the paths depending on where you put the jslint.js file.
The [conf.txt](http://lynet.ca/~alumb/jslint/conf.txt) file looks like this:

```
/*jslint forin:true*/
```

Make sure there is no return carriage at the end of this line. If there is a return  carriage all the lines counts will be off by one.

Finally, the command I entered into NppExec is:

```
"C:\Program Files\jslint\jslint.bat" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

### 2) Javascript Lint

[Javascript lint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/) is a slightly less strict parser and was much easier to implement.

First grab a copy of the windows version from http://www.javascriptlint.com/download.htm and unzip it. 
Then the NppExec command is:

```
"C:\Program Files\JavascriptLint\jsl.exe" -conf "C:\Program Files\JavascriptLint\jsl.default.conf" -process "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

(note: Most instructions for Javascript Lint will say to add "pauseatend" to the end of the command, I found this caused problems in Notepad++ so I left it off)

Hope this helps someone,
Cheers,
Andy.

Comment: Thank you for the Javascript Lint reference. I like it much better than JSLint but most people tend to leave it out.

Comment: Followed your instructions for JSLint and notepad++ and it worked. thanks.

Comment: Link for Javascript lint download is broken. it's: http://www.javascriptlint.com/download.htm

Comment: Thanks. For me NppExec plugin was not installed. I did Plugins->Plugin Manager-> Available and clicked on NppExec to install it.

Comment: for javascript lint, dont forget to add the NppExec console output filter '%ABSFILE%(%LINE%): *'

Answer (score 4):

After you've installed the plugin you should go to:

Plugins -> JSLint -> JSLint options

and change "Choose JavaScript lint tool:" to **JSHint**.

JSHint gives alot less meaningless "errors".