# Integrating JavaScript Lint in Notepad++

Tags: javascript, syntax, notepad++, lint

Followed directions in [Using JSLint in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046810/using-jslint-in-notepad). Using JavaScript Lint (not JSLint).

I am using jQuery library. How do you ignore the 300 jQuery warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your conf.txt add

`/*global $, jQuery*/`

Comment: Do you mean the jsl.default.conf file?
I added it to the end, but I got the error: 
C:\Program Files\JavascriptLint\jsl.default.conf(131): configuration error: unrecognized line format

Looking through the conf file it seems like the syntax is wrong...

Comment: Maybe I was just looking at the link you posted and it seemed the conf.txt in the accepted answer was the place.