# Java Script without usage of any automation Tool

Tags: javascript, automation

Is it possible that we can automate tests using Java Script without usage of any Tool?

Such like, if we can write a Java script in a notepad for automating a test, save it as a JS file and run it for perfect execution?

Any help/helpful link is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, please refer to the following question: 
[Using JSLint in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046810/using-jslint-in-notepad)