# Checking JavaScript code for typos in Notepad++

Tags: javascript, validation, notepad++

I use a combination of Notepad++, JSHint and Cordova CLI to create my hybrid Android web apps - yes, I am aware that there are more sophisticated ways of doing this but tht is not what this question is about.

One of the issues I run into every now and again is a typographic - as opposed to syntactic which is easily caught by JSHint - error which only manifests itself once I am compiled the APK and tried to run it.  For instance

- docment instead of document (missing u)
- getElmentByID  instead of getElementById (missing e, wrong capitalization on ID)

The one thing I really love about Java is that the compiler stops you dead in your tracks and demands that you fix such errors first.  That is not the case with JavaScript where the best one can do is test for correct syntax.

However, I am wondering - perhaps there is a way (maybe a NPP plugin that I am unaware of) to check for such errors?

Comment: Related: [Using JSLint in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046810/using-jslint-in-notepad)

Comment: JSLint does not catch `docment.getElementById` in place of `document.getElementById`.  I prefer jshint.com, not the JSLint NPP plugin which I find too opinonated.

Comment: Consider using Typescript, its a compiled version of Javascript and should catch such errors.

Comment: JSHint `unused: true, undef: true, browser: true` should find a lot of those things while recognising common browser globals. Catching properties/methods with static code analysis is impossible in Javascript, since objects can change at runtime.

Comment: Most syntax highlighters should also make that kind of error pretty obvious.  Failing that, typescript or flow type will scream at you before ya even hit save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) or [flowtype](https://flow.org/) to catch those, and many more errors.  Alternatively, find a decent syntax theme that's set up to highlight DOM methods.

Comment: Using a theme that highlights DOM methods is a neat idea. I could not find a ready made theme that does that so I just went and created one off my own.